# Best way to Join on Date Range PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

This Periscope Data Blog posts describes how to use the SQL query below to find the number of users who visited your website this month who also came last month, i.e. "retention":

```
with monthly_activity as (
  select distinct
    date_trunc('month', created_at) as month,
    user_id
  from events
)
select
  this_month.month,
  count(distinct user_id)
from monthly_activity this_month
join monthly_activity last_month
  on this_month.user_id = last_month.user_id
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '1 month' -- date join
group by month
```

But what if retention is defined as not "visited last month" but "visited *in any month in the past*"?

In that case, we would want the date join (highlighted as a comment in the above query) for not just 1 month in the past but *all* months in the past.

I.e. something like this, but without hardcoding:

```
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '1 month' 
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '2 month' 
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '3 month' 
  ...
```

I'm stumped on what's the best way to do this.

I've tried the following workarounds, although I think they lead to weird cartesian products since my queries aren't running:

```
AND current_month.month > past_logs.month -- doesn't run
```

and

```
AND past_logs.month IN (select i::date from generate_series('2014-10-01', 
                        current_month.month, '1 month'::interval) i) -- doesn't run
```

Thoughts on best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but wouldn't that be a simple `from monthly_activity where month < date_trunc('month', current_date)` without the need for a self join?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That would get retention for the current month. How about retention for past months?

Comment: That's why I used `<` and not `=`

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. Why are you using `current_date`? I want to get retention for this month, then retention for last month, and then the month before that, etc.

Your suggestion gets the count of users for each month in the past.

Comment: this problem seems ill defined, what results do you want, some sample data would help too, say you have only one user`Joe` active in jan,feb, april, and june.  - what is the result-set you want?